# Dynamic fields in FieldArray

Tags: redux-form

I've implemented `redux-form` in my whole app and it's going great. But I'm currently confused on how I would tackle the following case as I can't seem to find the best way to do this.

**Case**

I'm using a `select` component in my `Field` which is working as expected. This `Field` holds an array of values such as `['NL', 'EN']` and is has a name of `languages`.

---

**Issue**

Based on the values of the `languages` field, I need to create a `FieldArray`. How would I programatically create these fields without changing other `Fields`.

---

**Thoughts**

I first thought that I just would use `initialize` every time the `languages` field changes but I can't as there will already be information typed in the `FieldArray` or other `Fields` of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I've switched to the approach of using a `FormSection` and just using `languages.map(language => <Field ... />)` inside it. This works fine :)